# Передача пакетов между интерфейсами

Tags: linux, c, сокет, bridge

Делаю мост L2 с помощью raw sockets.. Пакеты вижу, вроде передаю в другой интерфейс (ошибок не возникает), а связи через мост нет.. что делаю не так?
Код ниже.. Может кто носом ткнуть?

```
char *opt_in  = "eth0";
char *opt_out = "eth1";

int sock;

int doexit = 0;

void sig_handler(int sig)
{
    switch(sig)
    {
        case SIGKILL :
        case SIGINT  :
        case SIGTERM :  {
                    doexit = 1;
                    break;
                }
        default :   {
                    break;
                }
    }
}




int main()
{


    sock = socket( AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL) );
    if (sock < 0) 
    {
        printf("Can't open socket\n");
        return 4;
    }


    struct sockaddr_ll sll; 
    int sll_size = sizeof( sll );

    unsigned char buf[ 1024 ];
    unsigned int  buf_size = 1024;

    struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) buf;



    struct ifreq if_idx1, if_idx2;
    struct ifreq if_flg1, if_flg2;
    int flg1, flg2;

    //-- Получаем индексы интерфейсов 
    memset(&if_idx1, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_idx1.ifr_name, opt_in, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if ( ioctl( sock, SIOCGIFINDEX, &if_idx1) < 0)
        perror("SIOCGIFINDEX 1");

    memset(&if_idx2, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_idx2.ifr_name, opt_out, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if ( ioctl( sock, SIOCGIFINDEX, &if_idx2) < 0)
        perror("SIOCGIFINDEX 2");



    //-- ставим  promiscuous mode  на оба интерфейса
    memset(&if_flg1, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_flg1.ifr_name, opt_in, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if ( ioctl( sock, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &if_flg1) < 0)
        perror("SIOCGIFFLAGS 1");
    flg1 = if_flg1.ifr_flags;
    if_flg1.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
    if ( ioctl( sock, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &if_flg1) < 0)
        perror("SIOCSIFFLAGS 1");


    memset(&if_flg2, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_flg2.ifr_name, opt_out, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if ( ioctl( sock, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &if_flg2) < 0)
        perror("SIOCGIFFLAGS 2");
    flg2 = if_flg2.ifr_flags;
    if_flg2.ifr_flags |= IFF_PROMISC;
    if ( ioctl( sock, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &if_flg2) < 0)
        perror("SIOCSIFFLAGS 2");



    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTTIN, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGHUP, sig_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, sig_handler);




    int i;

    printf("ready\n");


    unsigned long readed;



    while( !doexit )
    {

        //-- читаем что-нибудь от кого-нибудь
        readed = recvfrom( sock, buf, buf_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sll, &sll_size );

        //-- отфильтровываем пакеты с управляющего нтерфейса..
        if ( sll.sll_ifindex == 3 )
            continue;


        if ( readed > 0 )
        {

            //-- если пришло с одного интерфейса, шлём на другой (ставим нужный индекс интерфейса)
            if ( sll.sll_ifindex == if_idx1.ifr_ifindex )
            {
                sll.sll_ifindex = if_idx2.ifr_ifindex;
            }
            else
            {
                sll.sll_ifindex = if_idx1.ifr_ifindex;
            }
            sll.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;


            //-- копируем адрес "кому" из исходного пакета
            for( i=0; i<6; i++ )
                sll.sll_addr[ i ] = eh->ether_dhost[ i ] & 0xFF;


            if ( sendto( sock, buf, readed, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll) ) < 0 )
            {
                printf("Can't send to interface %d\n" , sll.sll_ifindex );
            }

        }



    }


    //-- по завершении - восстанавливаем флаги

    if_flg1.ifr_flags = flg1;
    if ( ioctl( sock, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &if_flg1) < 0)
        perror("SIOCSIFFLAGS 1x");

    if_flg2.ifr_flags = flg2;
    if ( ioctl( sock, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &if_flg2) < 0)
        perror("SIOCSIFFLAGS 2x");


    close( sock );

    printf("bye.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что ж вы так форматирование не любите... Пока поймешь, какая строка в каком блоке расположена, свихнешься.

Comment: Я бы через tap делал

Comment: Перехват *SIGKILL* — да ты Чак Норис!

Comment: И что, *ifr_name* разный получается?

Comment: @0andriy - всмысле, разный получается?...  он не получается, он задаётся. Два интерфейса, для каждого делаю одинаковые операции.   Видит трафик с обоих интерфейсов, а вот переслать по факту не выходит, хотя и ошибок не получаю. Что-то видимо упустил..

Comment: Как можно привязать один сокет сразу к двум интерфейсам?

Comment: @0andriy он вообще никуда не привязан. он raw. получает всё подряд. Откуда пришло - видим по индексу интерфейса.

Comment: `man 7 raw` читан до дыр?